# What does the term "Cross-section" mean in the context of empirical finance

Tags: cross-section

For instance, there is a paper entitled:
"Volatility Risk in the Cross‐Section of Stock Returns"

What does it mean to imply by the Volatility Risk in the cross-section of stock returns?

I know what volatility risk is, but specifically in the cross-section of stock returns does not make sense to me.

My guess is something along these lines:

This author may have looked at stock returns on the date of 1/01/2014 for 300 different stocks, and looked at the volatility of those stock return on that day, compared to the day before, for instance.

Is this understanding correct?

Comment: In nearly all literature -- financial, economic, I/O, statistical, etc. -- references made to 'cross-sections' refer to qualitative or categorical features of information. Stock returns can have many possible categorical features including (but not limited to): ticker symbols, SIC or NAICS codes (at varying levels of disaggregation, e.g., sectors down to 8-digit SIC codes), exchanges (e.g., NASDAQ vs NYSE), and so on.

Comment: ctd.  Without specifying a temporal interval, metrics such as 'volatility risk' don't mean very much. While your guess of day to day volatility in returns may be the correct temporal period, the author's introduction of the term 'cross-section' changes the focus of the analysis from within to between stocks.